# Remove white spaces that appear between rectangle shapes in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am rendering the rectangle continuously one by another in canvas. It create some white spaces between rectangle when rectangle values are in float value.

Please find the image below.

[image]

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20.5, 20.5);
ctx.arcTo(20.5, 20.5, 100.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 20.5, 100.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 70.5, 20.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(20.5, 70.5, 20.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100.5, 20.5);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 20.5, 180.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(180.5, 20.5, 180.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(180.5, 70.5, 100.5, 70.5, 0);
ctx.arcTo(100.5, 70.5, 100.5, 20.5, 0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="250" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
```

Can you please share how to over come this.

Comment: You should add your code that produces this output. That might help others to answer your question.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann I have include my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself, there are float values. If you remove the decimals, you won't see the white spaces anymore.
But in case you really can't change your values, maybe you can try to add this :

```
ctx.translate(0.5,0.5);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmerinian/a8fo64zn/4/)

Comment: I don't want to translate the canvas, because we have large number of rectangle with float values like 65.345 and 34.267. I have faced the same issue in SVG but I have fixed using shape-rendering="crispEdges". If any solution like this for canvas.